# I can't import a .gltf file in react with vite

Tags: reactjs, three.js, vite

I'm trying to import a gltf file in react with three.js but it can't find the file:

```
import { useLoader } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader";
import { Suspense } from "react";

const Model = () => {

  const gltf = useLoader(GLTFLoader, "../assets/SpainBoyPose.gltf");

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={null}>
      <primitive object={gltf.scene} />
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default Model;
```

Error:
`GET http://localhost:5173/assets/SpainBoyPose.gltf net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

I've tried using require to find the file but it doesn't work.

```
  const gltf = useLoader(GLTFLoader, require("../assets/SpainBoyPose.gltf"));
```

Error:  `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the option `assetsinclude` in your vite config  https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#assetsinclude ?

```
// vite.config.js
export default defineConfig({
  assetsInclude: ['**/*.gltf'],
})

// your react code
import meshUrl from '../assets/SpainBoyPose.gltf'

const gltf = useLoader(GLTFLoader, meshUrl)
```